# How can I use Promise or Defer to accomplish this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `app.run()` block that:

- uses an Angular service that uses a `$http.get` to get some values and sets them in the `$rootScope`
- calls another Angular component that uses the values from the `$http.get`

The issue is that the code in the second step runs before the HTTP call has replied with the values in the first step. I don't want the code in the second step to call the service directly.

How can I force the second step to wait for the first step to complete?

**service.js**

```
function getSomeConfigs() {
            var promise = $http.get('/blah');
            $rootScope.promise = promise
                .then(function () {
                    $rootScope.someVariable = data.someVariable;
                });
        }
```

**helper.js**

```
$rootScope.someVariable
is undefined
```

Comment: why don't you store the promise on `$rootScope` or better yet have your other component directly call the service?

Comment: Can you show us some of the code? It sounds like you should be calling your other component in the .success function of your get

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Please see edits.

Comment: when worse comes to worse, use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to emit an event when the `$http` has finished, which the helper.js listens with `$scope.$on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must chain the two steps:

```
$http.get('restAddress')
     .then(function(result) {
         $scope.myResult = result.data;             
     })
     .then(function() {
         MyFunctionIndirectlyDependingOnPreviousResult();
     });
```

You can even place the call to `MyFunctionIndirectlyDependingOnPreviousResult()` inside the first `then()` callback:

```
$http.get('restAddress')
     .then(function(result) {
         $scope.myResult = result.data;             
         MyFunctionIndirectlyDependingOnPreviousResult();
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

$HTTP service returns a promise.
So just set the return from your $http.get to a var and you can use the .then method.
e.g.

```
//Controller
....
//appSvc.get is a call to your .factory or .service that returns the promise
var inputUrl = "myUrl/REST/";
var promise = appSvc.get(inputUrl); 
promise.then(function (data) {
   //DO SOMETHING WITH Returned DATA
}
...

//SERVICE
'use strict';
module.exports = function (ngModule) {
  ngModule.factory('appSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {

      function epicUniverse (inputUrl) {
        return     $http.get(inputUrl);
      }

    return {
      get:epicUniverse

    };

  }]);
};
```